# Objective c static method returns the same value every time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm writing a custom xml deserializer for an iphone app. As you can see below, I'm looping through all the list elements in the xml, I have debugged it, and with each loop there is a new and different element. The problem is that the xpath helper methods (there are similar ones to the one posted below, but for int and decimal) always returns the same value.

For example - 1st loop's xml "SomeValue" value will be "abc" and the helper method will return "abc", second item comes around and its xml "SomeValue" is "XYZ", but the helper method will still return "abc".

I'm new to iphone/objective c/memory managment so it could be any number of things. I just cant determine what the problem is :( could someone please offer some help?

```
-(void) deserializeAndCallback:(GDataXMLElement *)response
{
    NSError * error;

    NSArray *listings = [response nodesForXPath:@"//ListingSummary" error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *deserializedListings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //loop through all listing elements, create a new listing object, set its values, and add
    //it to the list of deserialized objects.
    if(listings.count > 0)
    {

        for (GDataXMLElement *listingElement in listings) 
        {
            Listing *list = [[Listing alloc] init];

            //xpath helper function (shown below), just to get the value out of the xml
            list.someValue = [QuickQuery getString:listingElement fromXPath:@"//SomeValue"];

            [deserializedListings addObject:list];

        }
    }

    if([super.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(dataReady:)]) 
    {
        [super.delegate dataReady:deserializedListings];
    } 
}


+(NSString *) getString:(GDataXMLElement *)element fromXPath:(NSString *)xPath
{
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *result = [element nodesForXPath:xPath error:&error];

    if(result.count > 0)
    {
        GDataXMLElement *singleValue = (GDataXMLElement *) [result objectAtIndex:0];
        return singleValue.stringValue;
        [singleValue release];
    }
    return nil;
    [error release];
    [result release];

}
```

EDIT: ok... I found a bit more info. Inside the helper function, the nodesForXpath method returns all the nodes from the entire xml, not just the current element I'm busy with. Does GDataXMLElement keep reference to its parent elements at all?

Example of what the xml looks like

```
<ListingSummary>
    <SomeValue>abc</SomeValue>
</ListingSummary>
<ListingSummary>
    <SomeValue>jhi</SomeValue>
</ListingSummary>
<ListingSummary>
    <SomeValue>xyz</SomeValue>
</ListingSummary>
```

Comment: you can't do things after `return`

Comment: thanks... should have figured as much. but thats the lengths I've went to trying to solve this problem.

Comment: You shouldn't be releasing `singleValue`, `error`, or `result` anyways; you don't own them and you're not responsible for their memory. On the other hand, you _should_ be releasing `list` at the end of each loop; those are leaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is correct behaviour for the XPath query you are using. You actually want a query relative to the current node, not the root of the document as you are doing.

See http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

BTW `+ (NSString *)getString:(GDataXMLElement *)element fromXPath:(NSString *)xPath` is a class method, not a static method.

Comment: Thank you... using ./SomeValue worked. I will have to read up about class/static methods a bit, I don't think the distinction exists in C#

Answer (score 1):

You say that `nodesForXPath:` returns all the nodes from the whole document. Since you are calling that method with the same argument, `@"//SomeValue"`, every loop, you get back the same array every time. This means that `[result objectAtIndex:0]` gives you the same object every time.

Also, as I mentioned in a comment, you should not be releasing `singleValue`, `error`, or `result` in your helper method. You don't own those and you're not [responsible for their memory](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH27-SW1). On the other hand, since you create `list` using `alloc`, you *do* need to release it at the end of each loop; you are currently leaking a `Listing` object every pass.

Comment: This does not seem right though. I call nodesForXPath at two levels, once to get all the listing elements, and then again on each of those listing elements to get the specific properties off of it. The problme is, that it finds properties from all the listing elements in the original xml, not just from that sub element. I will add some example xml.

Comment: @Craigt: It seems strange to me too that it would work that way. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with `GDataXMLElement`. Have you looked at the `listings` array in the debugger?

Comment: Yeah, I have... It matches the XML. There are 4 listing summary elements in my XML. And there are 4 objects in the array. Each with the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks OK for me.  Although the releases inside the getString:fromXPath: aren't necessary (you don't need to release parameters entered into a method or objects obtained from a NSArray.  The proper way to release an object from a NSArray is removing it from the array, as for objects passed as a parameter, if you want to release it you should do it after you call the method.

The problem to your question must be somewhere else.

Answer (score -2):

`result.count` should be `[result count]` since count is a method and not a property of `NSArray`

Comment: I have changed that, still no diffs :(... as you can see above I found some more info.

Comment: Actually those are the same but the first is using objective-C 2.0 syntax.  Which I dislike and don't use, because it creates confusion as pointed out here.

Comment: `result.count` and `[result count]` are explicitly both supported. Dot-syntax is not limited to declared properties; anything that conforms to KVC naming conventions can be accessed via dot syntax.